# Strange MySQL results

Tags: mysql

I was wondering, why does the query

```
select * from (select * from users join users a) b
```

cause the `Duplicate column name` error? While the inner query returns a result set with duplicate columns, postfixed with _1, the outer one reveals a column from the table.

Comment: Because this can be the way to reveal all the columns from the table in a SQL injection (using USING)

Comment: Not sure I follow here. Surely, you should sanitize the input and put it within the appropriate quotes before even considering passing it as a parameter here (although you're not using parameters in this particular example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the proper behavior because any columns in the subquery select list must have unique name([Subqueries in the From Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/unnamed-views.html)). You can also check [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6709), it was a bug in old mysql versions that allowed you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

the columns in the sub query might have unique names so do this

```
select a.id, b.id, a.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from (select a.col1, a.id  from users join users a) b
```

where id,col1,col2,col3 are column names I made up